# How to create dynamic ajax function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm using many Ajax requests like:

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'file.php',
        type: 'POST',
        async: true,
        data: {'data' : data},
        success: function( data){
           //Do Something.
        }
});
```

So I'm wondering if it's possible to create a dynamic function and pass some parameters to that function like (file, type, data, successFunction).

Then whenever I want to make an Ajax request I call that function and pass these parameters.

Something like:

```
function dynamicAjax(fileName , reqType , dataObj , succFunction){
    $.ajax({
        url: fileName,
        type: reqType,
        async: true,
        data: dataObj,
        success: function( data){
           //Run The Passed Function (succFunction).
        }
    });
}
```

Then I execute that function :

```
dynamicAjax
('file.php' , 'POST' , {'data1': data1, 'data2': data2} , function(){
        //Do Something.
    }
);
```

Is that possible?

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: Have you tried exactly that? It should work fine. Having said that, is your `dynamicAjax` function any different to just using `$.ajax`?

Comment: Sounding like he's wanting to remove some perceived boiler plating in his app.

Comment: But that would just be a wrapper around $.ajax so what's the point? Down the line you'll surely want access to $.ajax:s other params as well at which point you'd have to update your own function which after a while will just be the same as $.ajax.

Comment: Why? It even doesn't decrease arguments number.

Comment: Less typing, perceived increase in readability.  There are various reasons a person might want to have a wrapper method for common logic.  The existence of the `$.get` and `$.post` methods do more than just wrapper the common logic.  They express explicitly the programmers intent.  You know they didn't type method: 'post' and actually meant to do a get.  They knew exactly what they wanted by using the method.

Comment: I think it will save a lot of code and instead of having about 10 lines of duplicating the same , Just duplicate one or two

Comment: @Taplar , Exactly.

Comment: Plus you can change the function later if you want to make it do something additional, without having to modify every single ajax request.

Answer (score 5):

jQuery took care of it, you're not the first one who get this idea.

check `$.get` and `$.post` methods in jQuery

```
$.post( "test.php", { param: "value" }, ( data )=>{/*function*/}, "json");

$.get( "test.php", ( data )=>{/*function*/}, "json");
```

Answer (score 1):

You were 99% there.  Just execute the callback function like so...

```
function dynamicAjax(fileName , reqType , dataObj , succFunction){
    $.ajax({
        url: fileName,
        type: reqType,
        async: true,
        data: dataObj,
        success: succFunction  // executes succFunction(data)
    });
}
```

Comment: Wrong... even if you insist to make your own function - to execute function passed as a parameter you need to invoke it within function body so parameter();

Comment: @DavidC. No, it's not wrong.  The `success` parameter of the ajax call is executed within the internal handler, so if you pass a function reference then that function will be called, with the success method parameters.  Try before you deny ;)

Comment: @DavidC. , the `succFunction` callback will be invoked within `ajax()` method.

Comment: @DavidC. both `success: function(){}` and `success: succFunction` are assigning the value of success in the properties to a function reference.  They are logically the same operation.  In both cases ajax will execute the function value stored in the success property when it needs to be ran.  It's the same pattern as things like `setTimeout(function(){ otherMethod(); }, 500)` works the same as `setTimeout(otherMethod, 500)`

Answer (score 0):

I have created a dynamic ajax function. Please check it.

```
function ajax(url, method = 'POST', data, callback)
        {
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                method: method,
                data: data,        
                headers: {
                    "Accept": "application/json",
                    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;",
                },
                beforeSend: function ()
                {

                },
                error: function (response)
                {
                    switch (true) {
                        case typeof response.responseText !== 'undefined':
                            console.log(response.responseText);
                            break;
                        case response.statusText !== 'abort' && e.status === 0:
                            alert('Please check your internet connection');
                            break;
                        case response.statusText === 'abort':
                            break;
                        default:
                            console.error(response);
                    }
                },
                complete: function (response)
                {

                        callback(response);

                }
            }
            );
        }
```

To call this function use this code like

```
ajax('url here', 'GET', {id: id}, function(response){
  alert(response);
});
```